# Blank page when trying to render props passed via Link route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, shopping-cart

I get a blank page when I try to render cart items passed from another page via Link.

When I console.log it works fine and shows an array.

How can I render them, this way or any other? I use the latest version of react-router

#### Catalog.js pass data

```
import { Header } from "./Header";
import {data} from './Data'
import ListProducts from "./ListProducts";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 export default function Catalog() {
    const {products} = data;
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

    const onAdd = (product) => {
        // const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
        setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product}]);

    }   


    return (
        <>
            <Header countCartItems={cartItems.length}/>
            <ListProducts products={products} onAdd={onAdd}/>
            <Link to={`/cart`} state={{ cartItems:{cartItems} }}>Cart</Link>
        </>
    )
}
```

#### Cart.js receive data

```
import './Cart.css'

import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Header } from './Header'

function Price(){
  return (
    <div className='price-cont'>
      <div className='price-cointainer'>
            <div className='total'>TOTAL</div>
            <div className='price'>00,00 €</div>
            <div className='checkout'>CHECKOUT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}

function Card(){
  const location = useLocation()
  const { cartItems } = location.state
    
  console.log(cartItems)

  return (
    <h1>{cartItems}</h1>
  )
}


export default function Cart(){
  

    return (
      <>
      <Header />
      
      <div className='cart-container'>
          <div className='item-container'>      
            <Card />
          </div>
      </div>
      <Price />
      </>
    );
  }
```

I tried  and  but it works this same

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the `cartItems` state array nested under a `cartItems` property.

```
<Link to={`/cart`} state={{ cartItems: { cartItems } }}>Cart</Link>
```

This means the route state is `state.cartItems.cartItems`.

You likely don't need the nesting. Just pass `cartItems` in the state.

```
<Link to={`/cart`} state={{ cartItems }}>Cart</Link>
```

This will make the route state `state.cartItems` like the component is expecting.

```
const { state } = useLocation()
const { cartItems } = state ?? [];
```